# Prove that the following function $f(X)=XX^{t}$ is differentiable

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let $M(n \times n) \simeq \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^{n^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ defined by
                $f(X)=XX^{t}$.

Prove que $f$ is differentiable and find $Df(X).A$.

I'm having a lot of difficulties in this exercise. I used the definition of Differentiability,, that is, $\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)-B.h}{||h||}\rightarrow 0$ as $h \rightarrow 0$. 
I only got

$\dfrac{(A+H)(A+H)^t - AA^t - BH}{||H||}=\dfrac{AH^t + HA^t+ HH^t - BH}{||H||}$.

Does anyone have any idea how to proceed? Or a better idea?

Comment: You may figure out that $$D_A f(X) = XA^{\mathsf{T}} + AX^{\mathsf{T}},$$ which is of course a linear function of $A$. This is equivalent to saying that $$ f(X+A) = f(X) + XA^{\mathsf{T}} + AX^{\mathsf{T}} + o(\|A\|) $$ as $A \to 0$.

Comment: Every entry of $X X^\top$ is a quadratic polynomial in the entries of $X$ and, thus, differentiable.

Comment: You did not understand the definition. Replace $BH$ by $\phi(H)$ where $\phi$ is linear. In a second time, choose $\phi(H)=AH^T+HA^T$ (which is linear as wrote  Sangchul Lee).